# Python repeat function two times when memorize a variable

Tags: python, function

I'm creating a function in python that is repeated two times when it ends even if it doesn't have to do it.

```
def first ():
   numuser = int(input("Write a number"))

   if(0 < numuser < 26):
      print("Ok")
   else:
     print("Wrong!, restart it!")
     first()  #If the number is out of the range it restart the function
   return numuser
first()

def second():
   numuserfirst = first()  #retrive the number choosen in the first function
second()
```

Repetition is caused by the variable call `numuserfirst = first()`, how can I solve it?
Thanks

Comment: One problem: you aren't returning the return value of the recursive call.

Comment: @chepner and how can I solve it?

Comment: Do not use recursion for this. Also consider using an exception handler (ValueError) to manage cases where the input cannot be converted to *int*

Answer (score 0):

Don't use recursion to implement a simple loop; use a `while` statement. One possible implementation:

```
def first():
    while True:
        numuser = int(input("Write a number"))
        if 0 < numuser < 26
            break
        print("Wrong!, try again")

    print("OK")
    return numuser
```